# How to apply a first order filter with a different time constant for each column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, signal-processing

everyone! I have a pandas dataframe where each column represents a noisy signal, and I would like to apply a first order filter (gain = 1, time constant = "x" seconds) in each column, but with a different time constant for each column. For example:

```
Column_A --> Time constant = 5 secs
Column_B --> Time constant = 15 secs
Column_C --> Time constant = 60 secs
Column_D --> Time constant = 200 secs
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` with the `args` passed as a tuple like so:

```
def your_filter_func(x, gain, time_constant):
    return some_filter(x, gain, time_constant)

df = df.apply(your_filter_func, args=(gain, time_constant), axis=0)
```

This applies `your_filter_func` to each column (that's the axis=0 part).

If you also want to apply a separate `gain` and `time_constant` to each column, you can do this by using the index of the column and adjusting accordingly:

```
def your_filter_func2(column, gains, time_constants):
    return some_filter(x, gains[column.index], time_constants[column.index])

df = df.apply(your_filter_func2, args=(gains, time_constants), axis=0)
```

And just make sure that the `gains` and `time_constants` are an iterable (e.g. list or numpy array) where you can index into it by the index of the column, to pull out the specific gain and time_constant for that column.

Comment: the "gain" and "time_constant" will be each one a tupple? I mean, I need different gains and time constants for each column, so that's why a assumed that. Is that correct?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, and did not realize you wanted a separate gain and time_constant for each column. I've updated my answer. If that's what you were looking for, please accept the answer!

Comment: I guess the answer is ok for the "apply" part, but I'm still not sure on how to do the "first order filter". Anyway, I guess I should have divided the question in two. Thanks